# Numpy array sum each column values based on the label column for high dimension datasets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, group-by

i'm trying to learn numpy mechanism. I have an numpy array with high dimension. What i want is to get an array or list which stores the sum of each column grouped by the labels. For example, the features looks like:

```
array([[-16.99176812,  -2.36223789,  -1.87838669, ...,   0.06839992,
         -0.03640378,  -0.54913372],
       [-17.83648228,   1.28261146,  -0.62738817, ...,   0.08641197,
         -0.09980481,  -0.08203106],
       [-16.63403339,   4.33705931,  -2.29143763, ...,  -0.2422984 ,
         -0.59537268,  -0.35633719],
       ...,
```

And the label is given from a different array ranged from 0 up to 9:

```
array([6, 0, 1, ..., 1, 2, 2]
```

How do i get the sum of each column based on their labels using numpy? I have done this using pandas by creating a dataframe which combine these two arrays together and use df.groupby().mean(). However to achieve my target output,it goes tedious if i first transfer them into dataframe and convert the output back to an numpy array. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a more minimal dataset to verify solutions?  You can probably use `np.add.at`

Comment: Convert the inputs into a dataframe and get the numpy array back only cost you like one more line of code. Unless you need the ultimate hardcore numpy solution, I don't think a pure numpy version can be any shorter in term of coding.

Comment: @user3483203 the dataset is actually quite large. As Hoang commented, i'll use pandas as it seems like to be the easiest way to solve the question

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah, i've noticed using pandas might be the simplest way to solve it. Just wondered if the numpy library contains any such function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.add.at` method (I think, based on the problem spec):

```
output = np.zeros((10, input.shape[1]))
np.add.at(output, labels, input)
#since you seem to want `mean`
output /= np.bincount(labels)
```